# Employee Table and Manager Table

Tags: sql, join

I have Employee Table

```
EMPID  | EMPNAME    
1      | A        
2      | B
```

I have [Manager Table]

```
MNGID  | EMPID    
2      | 1
```

The above MNGID Refers TO Employee Table Means B is the Manager of A.

I wanted query  to display Manager Name and Employee Name. Please Sugget Result

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+join)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job for you:

```
select E.EmpName as EmployeeName, EM.EmpName as ManagerName
FROM Employee E
join Manager M on E.EMPID = M.EMPID
join Employee EM on M.MngID = EM.EMPId
```

Answer (score 0):

try this[Updated query]:

```
SELECT 
    m1.empname as manager,
    e.empname as employee
FROM
    Manager m
JOIN
    Employee e
ON
    m.empid = e.empid
JOIN
    Employee m1
ON
    m1.empid = m.mngid
```

================

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61560b/1

Comment: Its Incomplete Query

Comment: select e1.Name EMPName, m1.MNGName from EMP e1 
right join (
select m.empId, e.Name as MNGName  from MNG m
left join EMP e on e.Id= m.MNGID) m1
on e1.Id = m1.empId